# Prevent Excel cell being protected when when copying formulas via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm using VBA code to insert a new line in a Excel 2016 worksheet and then I copy the formulas from the above line to the new line so that I don't have to insert them manually. Unfortunately the cell where the formula is inserted is protected after copying the formula. This brings the disadvantage that I cannot delete the new row if I made a mistake. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Disable events to prevent that insertion of the row triggers a new Worksheet_Change
' event. Without this action the worksheet would be in an endles loop.
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Cells(Target.Row + 2, 1).Value = "end" Then
        Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End If

' Copy formulas
Cells(Target.Row - 1, 2).Copy (Cells(Target.Row, 2))
Cells(Target.Row - 1, 5).Copy (Cells(Target.Row, 5))
Cells(Target.Row - 1, 2).Unprotect
Cells(Target.Row - 2, 5).Unprotect


' Reactivate events so that the worksheet can react to user changes.
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

As you can see I also tried to unprotect the cell but this doesn't help. What can I do to prevent these cells from being protected after copying the formula? I'm trying this for hours now and Google didn't answer my question until now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192187/how-to-have-unlocked-cells-on-a-protected-vba-created-worksheet). looks like you need to unprotect the entire sheet first, then set which cells to leave unlocked, then proctect the sheet again.