# VBA Excel: Moving data macro error on protected sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following example code in a module of VBA:

```
Sub My_Code()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("A1") = "Main Data"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Secondary").Range("A2").Copy Sheets("Main").Range("B2")

End Sub
```

and to protect the sheets, Main and Secondary, I have put the following code in Thisworkbook of VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("Main").Protect Password:="Mypassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Secondary").Protect Password:="Mypassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

When I run `My_Code()` I get the error:

""Run-time error '1004'
The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet.
To make changes, click Unprotect Sheet in the Review tab (you might need a password).""

And this debugs to the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Secondary")....` line.

When I manually Unprotect the Main sheet the code runs. Any ideas why I can't leave Main protected? Have I forgotten something?

Comment: Perhaps this gets you going: Thisworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("B2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Secondary").Range("A2").Value

Comment: @jkpieterse This does solve the problem but only for this code, If I substitute this fix into my main code I get a "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the code I use to conditionally format cells . My actual program is a few 1000 lines so I can't but it in. By do you know why Protecting the code stops it from running correctly?

Comment: One thing to watch out for here.. if you set the password in the way you have, there will be no error if it failed. So if the password isn't currently set to "MyPassword", the whole line is ignored and you're not made aware. Coupled with the fact that when the Workbook is saved, closed and reopened it removes the `UserInterfaceOnly` part of the protection it is quite possible that `UserInterfaceOnly` isn't set to the `True` that you think it is. Check that there are no other alternative passwords or protections being set elsewhere in your code and that the user isn't over-riding it.

Comment: @CLR Thanks for the heads up. I walked through my code and there was no other passwords or protections in my code. The password part of my code was placed in the work book under `Private sub Workbook_Open()` which is run when the work book is opened, so the `UserInterfaceOnly` is set true every time the workbook is opened.

Comment: I've also seen people use `Workbook.Activate` event instead of `Workbook.Open`. I've never looked into why other than they have similar issues to you but this might be something to try?

Comment: @CLR I haven't used either of those in my code. 
When I try the not so secure 

`Sheets("Main").UnProtect Password:="Mypassword"`
`'my code`
`Sheets("Main").Protect Password:="Mypassword"`

approach the code works again which makes me think it has something to do with the UserInterfaceOnly.

Comment: I've seen quite some cases where the UIOnly setting does not prevent RT errors from happening, even though they shouldn't. All you can do is try modifying the syntax. Excel 2013 and 2016 have become even more finicky about this and about what is the active workbook and/or worksheet as well when trying to modify portected sheets from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jkpieterse Gave the solution to this question which was to change the second line of the My_Code() to

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("B2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Secondary").Range("A2").Value
```

However this created a new error in my code which is mentioned in the comments about. The who reason behind this problem is that the `UserInterfaceOnly = true` does not allow macros to modify the sheet, it only allows for value changes. Therefore there is no way to use the interface protect work around when you modify the worksheet. The only solution from here is:

```
Sub My_Code()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

ws.UnProtect Password:="Mypassword"

On Error GoTo ErrHandeler

ws.Range("A1") = "Main Data"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Secondary").Range("A2").Copy ws.Range("B2")

ws.Protect:="Mypassword"

ErrHandler:
ws.Protect:="Mypassword"
End Sub
```

This is the next most secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

The cells that you want to populate data in or modify needs to be `unlocked`.  So select the range of cells, then in `format cell` set them to be `unlocked`. When you password protect the sheet, make sure you check `allow to edit unlocked cells`.
Try this with you original code, it should work. Since it worked when you unprotected the sheet.

Comment: This would work but it would mean the cells are not protected and I would like them to be protected :(

Comment: Maybe try to use VBA to unlock the cells right before you run your code, then right after your code ran, lock the cells.  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192187/how-to-have-unlocked-cells-on-a-protected-vba-created-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have to reset the protection with  `UserInterfaceOnly = True` upon `Workbook_Open`, which resolves my issue. Excel closes the workbook with a default of `UserInterfaceOnly = False` (even though I run the secure commands on the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event.