# sheet protection in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to protect a worksheet, the code where I get an error is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
 If cell.Value <> "" Then
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Else
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
 Next cell
End Sub
```

In this piece of code I get an error ***The hidden property of the range object can not be determined***. This runtime error occurs because I want to make a specific area unlocked but not the whole sheet as I mentioned. Can I change the code to make this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide cells in excel automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501860/hide-cells-in-excel-automatically)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, yes but not the question only the code :D

Answer (score 0):

Your range object is not working properly.

So just use the dynamic index for the range like. You have to use  dynamic index here like `Range("B"+ +""+ index +":"B"+ +""+ index +"")` and index is dynamically increase.

Your `cell` is not set as range of entire row.
**Something like:**

Range("B" & + index &:"B" & + index).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Please see below if helpful to you.

```
wks.Range("A" & 7 & ":A" & NumRows + Firstrow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Comment: thx @Shivaji Kokate. Can you tell me where I have to insert your code? I am a little bit confused now :D

Comment: I have updated the my example in the answer. See if helpful to you.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. But I'm honest I am not sure if this is that what I need. In my code the hide function works good for hiding the empty cells in range B6:B112. The problem is only when I want to protect the whole sheet and then unlock the area for example D6:BC16 it falls under B6:B112 because of _EntireRow_ and I don't now how to fix that :(

Comment: You can unprotect sheet before use. So you can apply formula on specific range like unprotect. After your use you can again protect the entire sheet if needed. I think this is the best reference. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192187/how-to-have-unlocked-cells-on-a-protected-vba-created-worksheet**

Comment: should I use the code of the function _UnlockCells()_ from the link you posted? @Shivaji Kokate

Comment: Might be it will work without password. Otherwise it will ask for password.
 ws.Unprotect Password:="password"
 Target.Locked = False
 ws.Protect Password:="password"

Added in second answer of that reference.

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to hide an entire sheet, you should consider doing this :

```
Sheets("Yoursheetname").Visible = Hidden
```

or

```
Sheets("Yoursheetname").Visible = xlVeryHidden
```

Comment: Yes it is, but in this sheet I want to unhide a area for other users you know?

Comment: Okay I see your problem. In that case the issue is coming from the use of EntireRow. This call affects the entire width of the excel file which is definitively not what you want to do. I suggest determining the width and height of the excel file first (use a do while loop for that) and then specifiy a range to hide the corresponding values.

Comment: yes!! do you know how I can fix that? @Diveye because I need this Hidden function for an specific Range

Comment: Dim length As Integer
    
    length = 1
    Do While (Not IsEmpty(Sheet("Change").Cells(length, 1)))
        length = length + 1
    
    Loop
    length = length - 1 'remove the last element which is empty